# Running QEMU Agent with both guest and host running Windows 10

Tags: qemu

I want to set up QEMU agent to make it easier for the host machine to communicate with the virtual machine. The examples I found use Linux on host machine, but I need it to work on Windows 10.

I think I should use pipes instead of sockets, but I haven't been able to make it work.